# Outlook plugin search with RegEx

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, outlook-addin

I'm trying to create a Outlook 2013 plugin that can search for mails using a Regex expression but I have run into some problems.

I'm using the following to get the inbox items.

```
Outlook.MAPIFolder inbox = this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
Outlook.Items items = inbox.Items;
```

I then loop the items and check the body for a regex match

```
Match match = rgx.Match(mail.Body);
if (match.Success)
{ //do something     }
```

I have 2 problems with the solution

- I only get items that is up to 1 year old. How do I get all mails regardless of age?
- Is there a quicker way to search using RegEx ?

I hope someone can help

Comment: Please show your loop that iterates over the items.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have configured an Exchange cached account in Outlook with a 1-year cached data. You need to check that in the profile settings. As a possible workaround you may use [EWS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877012(v=exchg.150).aspx) or Extended MAPI to bypass the cached data.

> I then loop the items and check the body for a regex match

Iterating through all items in the folder is not really a good idea. I'd recommend using the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods of the `Items` class to get a subset of items that correspond to your conditions.

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

Also you may find the `AdvancedSearch` method of the `Application` class helpful. The key benefits of using the `AdvancedSearch` method in Outlook are:

- The search is performed in another thread. You don’t need to run another thread manually since the `AdvancedSearch` method runs it automatically in the background.
- Possibility to search for any item types: mail, appointment, calendar, notes etc. in any location, i.e. beyond the scope of a certain folder. The Restrict and `Find`/`FindNext` methods can be applied to a particular Items collection (see the Items property of the Folder class in Outlook).
- Full support for DASL queries (custom properties can be used for searching too). You can read more about this in the [Filtering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208216%28v=office.12%29) article in MSDN. To improve the search performance, Instant Search keywords can be used if Instant Search is enabled for the store (see the `IsInstantSearchEnabled` property of the `Store` class).
- You can stop the search process at any moment using the Stop method of the Search class.

Read more about this in the [Advanced search in Outlook programmatically: C#, VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/05/31/outlook-search-csharp-vbnet/) article.